# not able to send image in firebase push notification using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification with image using node.js. Our mobile app is developed in react native. The notification is going properly with the title and body but the image is not going in the notification.

This is the code snippets

```
let topic = 'TOPIC_NAME';

let message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'PN Title',
    body: 'push notification body push notification body push notification body push notification body push notification body push notification body',
    imageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/opdlift-hcpappforclinics.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2Fpnggrad16rgb.png?alt=media&token=dcae7645-169b-4d8b-b7d5-8b34452fd3da"
  },
  topic: topic
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {

    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

can you please tell me what I am missing here? I have checked in the library that it accepts the title, body, and imageUrl

Comment: Try replacing imageUrl key with image inside the notification payload. According to firebase docs, Image url should be provided with image key and not imageUrl key. Here is the link to the firebase doc -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image

Comment: Write it as :
  notification: {
            title: 'NotifcationTestAPP',
            body: '{"Message from node js app"}',
            image:'https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg'
        },